# Improve code readability of code generated through RealTime Workshop

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

I model embedded software components using Matlab/Simulink and the I generate C code using RealTime Workshop.
I'm trying to improve code readability and logical structure of the generated code.
Do you have any idea about how to instruct Simulink and/or RealTime Workshop to produce better code? Is it possible to give some hint to the code generation task or somethig like that?

Comment: Do you have any specific examples of what's wrong with the current output?

Comment: I can't cut & paste source code. Anyway, the main problems are the following:
1. I would like to force some more meaningful names for variables
2. I would like to do the same thing with data structures in such a way to increase code readability;
3. I would like to be able to give some hint about function calls parameters, return values and function names...
Whatever is useful to have a better readability of the code...

Comment: This can be done, but usually at an enormous upfront time spent on configuration, then if you have another model different enough, you may decide that it is not readable either.  Really, I would just recommend using the most recent Matlab/Simulink release.  Aside, why do you want more readable C code?

Answer (score 0):

The readiness depends on the System Target File (stf) you are using, this can be selected from the Configuration Parameters>Code Generation>System Target File. Typically, the Generic Target File (grt.tlc) does not care about readiness of the code since it is aiming to just use the generated code to be built and used in a target. If you want to have a clean code and more easy to read you would need to change the STF to "ert" which is for embedded system, more efficient and easy to read.

There is a catch though, you might need to pay a little more to get this "ert" feature.